# Yii too many redirects on userlogin

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, frameworks, yii

I am getting errors for too many redirects in Yii.

I am using the default accessControl filter provided by Yii.

The whole application works perfectly on localhost, where i am using WAMP. The problem started occuring after i uploaded to a staging server.

I have configured the .htaccess file to the best of my knowledge

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

If i try to open any action where login is not required it opens without a glitch

```
public function accessRules()

{

    return array(

        array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions

            'actions' => array('index', 'locationImport', 'contact'),

            'users' => array('*'),

        ),

        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions

            'actions' => array('LocationImport'),

            'users' => array('@'),

        ),

        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions

            'actions' => array('admin', 'delete'),

            'users' => array('admin'),

        ),

        array('deny', // deny all users

            'users' => array('*'),

        ),

    );

}
```

In the above controller the contact is working.

my main.php relevant

```
'user' => array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl' => array('/useraccount/login'),
        'class' => 'CPWebUser',
    ),
```

Access rules in UserAccountController

```
 public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'register' and 'login' actions
            'actions' => array('register', 'login', 'view', 'xxxx', 'xxxx',),
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions' => array('update', 'logout', 'home', 'changePassword'),
            'users' => array('@'),
        )
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Just to sum up.
completely works on localhost.
sitecontroller Actioncontact works.
No action in userAccountController works. Not even register, it redirects to login.
actionLogin doesnt open.

Comment: You should enable the debug log in mod_rewrite to get a clue what's going on. This requires access to the Apache config file, tough.

Comment: What is your cookie domain set to in your main.php?

Comment: I did all that and spent hours with htaccess and php configurations. But finally found the solution to be a silly mistake. posting as answer.. Though if anyone else has some problem now can answer quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It was as silly a mistake as could be. After hours of working, problem got solved because of a typo.

On linux the main.php config becomes case sensitive, i was programming on windows where it was not.

my controller was userAccount and the

```
'loginUrl' => array('useraccount/login'),
```

just changed it to

```
'loginUrl' => array('userAccount/login'),
```